# How do I get the key bindings to work in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game in python using pygame where two spaceships (red & yellow) shoot projectiles at each other. When it came to writing the code which fired the projectiles for red, I binded the shoot key to the letter "u" on my keyboard. However, when I press "u", the projectile doesn't fire.

Later on in debugging, I noticed that you have to be holding down the "l" key (which makes red move to the right) and the spaceship has to have a velocity to the right for the bullet to fire.

I also downloaded some files for the spaceship images and background, which can be found here (after clicking link, click "Code", then "Download ZIP", then move it to your python files): https://github.com/techwithtim/PygameForBeginners

Code:

```
import pygame
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Spaceship Game")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

FPS = 60
VEL = 5

BULLET_VEL = 7
MAX_BULLETS = 3

BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2 - 5, 0, 10, HEIGHT)
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55, 40

YELLOW_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
RED_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 2

YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join("Assets", "spaceship_yellow.png"))
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(
    pygame.transform.scale(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 90)

RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join("Assets", "spaceship_red.png"))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (55, 40)), 270)

SPACE = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join("Assets", "space.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets):
    WIN.blit(SPACE, (0, 0))

    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, BORDER)
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (red.x, red.y))

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, bullet)

    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, bullet)

    pygame.display.update()


def yellow_handle_movement(keys_pressed, yellow):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and yellow.y - VEL > 0:  # UP KEY YELLOW
        yellow.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x - VEL > 0:  # LEFT KEY YELLOW
        yellow.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and yellow.y + VEL + yellow.height < HEIGHT - 15:  # DOWN KEY YELLOW
        yellow.y += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and yellow.x + VEL + yellow.width < BORDER.x:  # RIGHT KEY YELLOW
        yellow.x += VEL


def red_handle_movement(keys_pressed, red):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_i] and red.y - VEL > 0:  # UP KEY RED
        red.y -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_j] and red.x - VEL > BORDER.x + BORDER.width:  # LEFT KEY RED
        red.x -= VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_k] and red.y + VEL + red.height < HEIGHT - 15:  # DOWN KEY RED
        red.y += VEL
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_l] and red.x + VEL + red.width < WIDTH:  # RIGHT KEY RED
        red.x += VEL


def handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red):
    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        bullet.x += BULLET_VEL
        if yellow.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(RED_HIT))
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x > WIDTH:
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        bullet.x -= BULLET_VEL
        if red.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(YELLOW_HIT))
            red_bullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x < 0:
            red_bullets.remove(bullet)


def main():  # Main Game Loop
    red = pygame.Rect(700, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    yellow = pygame.Rect(100, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)

    red_bullets = []
    yellow_bullets = []

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q and len(yellow_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(yellow.x + yellow.width, yellow.y + yellow.height//2 - 2, 10, 5)
                    yellow_bullets.append(bullet)

                if event.key == pygame.K_u and len(red_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(red.x, red.y + red.height//2 - 2, 10, 5)
                    red_bullets.append(bullet)
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        yellow_handle_movement(keys_pressed, yellow)
        red_handle_movement(keys_pressed, red)

        handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red)

        draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets)


if __name__ == "__main__":  # Makes sure that the code won't run if imported 
    main()
```

You can run the code and see the problem for yourself, as I explain things very badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the yellow bullet collides with the red spaceship and the red bullet collides with the yellow spaceship and not the other way around.
Read also [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) and iterate through a shallow copy of the bulleted lists.

```py
def handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red):
    for bullet in yellow_bullets[:]:                       # <---
        bullet.x += BULLET_VEL
        if red.colliderect(bullet):                        # <---
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(RED_HIT))
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x > WIDTH:
            yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)

    for bullet in red_bullets[:]:                          # <---
        bullet.x -= BULLET_VEL
        if yellow.colliderect(bullet):                     # <---
            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(YELLOW_HIT))
            red_bullets.remove(bullet)
        elif bullet.x < 0:
            red_bullets.remove(bullet)
```